Responsive (hidden) columns are not persisting properly to the DataTable
I've created a test case, which you can view here:
Test case of DataTable responsive columns
In this scenario, I'm facing an issue where the values are not persisting correctly in the DataTable.
For example, when I change the Instrument Dropdown value using the onchange event, the corresponding values update as expected (you can check Future Price field). However, if I expand and collapse the row using the arrow (up/down), the values reset to their previous state instead of retaining the updated ones.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I'm quite new to working with DataTable integration.
Please help.
Thank you!
